# Info messages during CatBoost training

Tags: catboost

I am new to CatBoost and I am running CatBoostClassifier training with `logging_level = "Info"`. My data consists of both categorical and numerical variables.

Firstly, for one of the categorical variables, I get the following message in the printed info: `feature 21 is redundant categorical feature, skipping it`. How is the redundancy of this feature determined?

Furthermore, I'm a bit lost as to what all the info for the iterations stands for. Here is the info output for one single iteration of my training:

```
{Feature1} pr0 tb1 type0, border=10 score 2.001737609
Feature2, bin=40 score 2.867480488
{Feature3, Feature2 b40} pr2 tb2 type0, border=6 score  3.533462883
Feature4, bin=5 score 4.105045044
46: learn: -1.2759319   total: 13.2s    remaining: 843ms
```

In this case, Feature1 and Feature3 are categorical, while Feature2 and Feature4 are numerical.

What are all the values like `pr0`, `tb1`, `type0`, `score` etc. stand for? Any pointer to a documentation will be very appreciated.